# how to get the name of the object being detected in tensorflow using faster RCNN model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow's object detection api for detecting an object. I trained the model and its working fine but I want to get the name of the object being detected as a String. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

The API provides a tutorial file called [object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb), in this file, function `run_inference_for_single_image` returns a detection dictionary `output_dict` which contains the key `detection_classes`, this corresponds to the id you defined in the label_map.pbtxt file. Also in this file variable `category_index` is the label map stored as a dictionary. So to just get the string name of all the object detected, simply add:

```
string_name = [category_index[i] for i in output_dict['detection_classes']]
```

after this line `output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)` in the tutorial.